# Get data from local json file in Vuejs method using jQuery $.getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm working on a demo app using Vuejs, and as part of it, I need to get some map data from a local .json file, get certain parts of it (such as lat/long values), and then put it into the appropriate data objects so they can be displayed on a map. After doing a lot of searching it seems that the easiest way it to use jQuery's `$.getJSON()` method. However, what I can't figure out is how to get the data from within the `$.getJSON` callback to my Vue `markers` object.

Here's my relevant code:

```
<script>
import _ from 'lodash'
import $ from 'jquery'

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      center: {lat: 37.541885, lng: -77.440624},
      markers: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getMarkers: function () {
      var apparatus = {}
      var address = []
      var description = {}
      $.getJSON('../static/event1.json', function (data) {
        // What do I do here to get outside of this function so
        // I can manipulate it?
        apparatus = data.apparatus
        address = data.address
        description = data.description
      })
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getMarkers()
  }
}
</script>
```

As you can see by the comment above, I need to get the data from inside the `$.getJSON` callback, but I can't see what I need to do that. Will this way work, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where do you want to access this outside the function. 
For example, you can assign result of `$.getJSON` to Vue's instance data by `self.data = data`, then you can access it outside of your `$.getJSON`

```
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      center: {lat: 37.541885, lng: -77.440624},
      markers: [],
      data: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getMarkers: function () {
      var apparatus = {}
      var address = []
      var description = {}
      var self = this
      $.getJSON('../static/event1.json', function (data) {
        self.data = data // then you can access data outside of your function by reference this.data


        // What do I do here to get outside of this function so
        // I can manipulate it?

        apparatus = data.apparatus
        address = data.address
        description = data.description
      })
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getMarkers()
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that works, but what happens is that anything after the $.getJSON() calls is run before the $.getJSON callback, since it's asynchronous. How do I only run the code that manipulates the self.data after the getJSON callback has been run?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a way to use your data object's inside your method. You can use `this` to get access to your data object's :

```
this.markers = data;
```

UPDATE :

In your case, you have another scope in your method ( Your callback ) so you ned to use View Model. just before your getJSON line, define it like this :

```
var vm = this;
```

Then inside your callback, you can have access to your data object :

```
vm.markers = data;
```

notice that if you are using the older version's of vue ( below 2.x ) , you need to use it like this :

```
this.$data.markers = data;
```

Comment: When I looked at `this` inside the $.getJSON callback, it was the jQuery object, not the Vue component.

Comment: So you have a scope inside your method ( your callback ) then you need to use a View Model. before your getJSON, define var vm = this; and use it inside your callback. I will update the answer