# $.getJSON using dynamic variables

Tags: jquery, vue.js

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50342339/get-data-from-local-json-file-in-vuejs-method-using-jquery-getjson) encapsulates what I want to do, except I'd like to take it a step further. I want to use a single 'fetchData' function in my VueJS application to grab several different JSON files so I don't have to repeat the code for each file. Here's the relevant snippet:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      "theFirstJsonFile": {},
      "theSecondJsonFile": {},
      "theThirdJsonFile": {}
  },
mounted() {
    this.fetchData("database/firstFile.json", "theFirstJsonFile");
    this.fetchData("database/secondFile.json", "theSecondJsonFile");
    this.fetchData("database/thirdFile.json", "theThirdJsonFile");
},
methods: {
    fetchData(theDataFile, containerObject) {
        var vm = this;
        $.getJSON(theDataFile, function(thisData) {
          vm.containerObject = thisData;
          console.log(thisData);
          console.log(vm.containerObject);              
        })
          .done(function() {
            console.log( "Success loading "+theDataFile );
          })
          .fail(function() {
            console.log( "Error loading "+theDataFile ); 
          })
          .always(function() {
            console.log( "Completed" );
      });
    }
});
```

Both 'console.log' calls show the fetched data, but the container object itself remains emtpy. I realize I'm passing in the second argument as a string rather than as a data object; I was originally using 'this.theFirstJsonFile' (without quotes), but given that I'm defining var vm = this inside the fetchData function, it's now redundant. How do I reference the appropriate Vue data object inside my function in a way that equates to 'this.theFirstJsonFile', 'this.theSecondJsonFile', etc.?

Comment: Please try `vm[containerObject] = thisData`

Comment: Wow, simple solution. Want to make it an answer so I can give you credit for it?

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`containerObject` is a variable. To access this, you need to use square bracket:

```
vm[containerObject] = thisData
```

more details:

```
var containerObject = "theFirstJsonFile"
vm[containerObject] // === vm.theFirstJsonFile
vm.containerObject // === vm.containerObject
```